# Is it possible to batch the same photo multiple times over?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, batch-processing

I'd like to move a layer in my photo continuously, and save it in incrementing file names.

For example:

`1.png
2.png
3.png
...`

I heard about the batch tool, but that edits multiple photos rather than the same. I already have the action saved to do what I want it to do.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you maybe post a simplified image example of what you need to happen? I thought I understood, but I also thought that it wouldn't be possible with actions and you say you have a working action... So maybe I didn't quite understand. If you can't post the image, just dropbox link it to the question or something and some one will change it to img.

Comment: @Joonas a photo wouldn't really help, but if you know Ctrl+Shift+T. I basically need to automatically do that a couple hundred times and save them like mentioned.

Comment: You'll have to script it. Basically you need like a for loop that runs `x` amount of times and you could simplify it by using script listener to produce rest of the code.